# Steering wheel stiff

Tags: power-steering, volvo, 850

My steering wheel was groaning, especially when making sharp turns, so I mentioned to the mechanic when some other service was being done. He said it was low on fluid and he filled it.

After I got the car back, it no longer groans, but the wheel is quite stiff and difficult to turn.

What could be the problem?

1996 Volvo 850

Comment: Many possibilities, failing pump, failing rack, seized joints on rack ends or seized joints in the steering column.